# can't type Chinese on slack

Tags: ibus, chinese

I am relatively new to Ubuntu. I found out that I can't type Chinese in Slack but can elsewhere. Can't figure out why. Any one has the same problem?
My ubuntu is 18.04

Answer (score 9):

remove your snap version slack, and install deb version slack. Some snap based Apps do not fully support Ibus.